# How to run Ajax script on load of an HTML page?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have myfile.php, want to run this file first in myfile.html on load by using an ajax script. If its possible to do that? How? I don't want to use include and require.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question you can try .load method in jquery   for example

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#contents").load('url to myfile.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using simple Javascript - jQuery or any other library isn't required. First, Define `xhr`:

```
var xhr;

if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' );
}
```

Then, call the file, and output the result into an element with `id="output"` attribute:

```
var method, url, async;

method = 'get';          // Request - GET or POST?
url    = 'myfile.php';
async  = true;           // asynchronous - true, synchronous - false

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4 ) {
        document.getElementById( 'output' ) = this.responseText;
    } else {
        // File does not exist -or- any possible error
        document.getElementById( 'output' ) = 'An error occurred';
    }
}

xhr.open( method, url, async );
xhr.send();
```

[Learn more about Ajax on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).